# VBA calling class let method, compile error

Tags: vba, excel

Beginner to excel class modules here. I am having trouble with the basics-

When I set (let) the property, I get "Compile error: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assessment" with the `.Name` property:

```
Sub test()
    Dim acc As account
    Set acc = New account
    MsgBox (acc.Name("First Account").rowNum())
End Sub
```

And this is the "account" class module:

```
Private strAccName As String
Private mlngRowNum As Long


Public Property Let Name(strN As String)
    strAccName = strN
End Property


Public Property Get rowNum(exists As Boolean)
    dim rowNum as Long
    '...some logic here...
    '...
    getRowNum = rowNum
End Property
```

So supposedly I am going wrong in the Let method? Advice greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can assign a value to a property LET (for normal dataTypes) or property SET (for Object) by the equal sign, not vith parenthesis (used for method instead), or read a property GET assigning the value to another variable, like this:

```
acc.Name = "xyz"
MsgBox acc.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

```
Sub test_class()
    Dim acc As account
    Set acc = New account
    acc.Name = "First Account"
    MsgBox acc.rowNum(1)
End Sub
```

class (account):

```
Private strAccName As String
Private mlngRowNum As Long

Public Property Let Name(strN As String)
    strAccName = strN
End Property


Public Property Get rowNum(exists As Boolean)
    'Dim rowNum As Long
    '...some logic here...
    '...
    If exists Then
    'getRowNum = rowNum
    rowNum = 5
    Else
    rowNum = 10
    End If
End Property
```